# Order in Layer в Sprite Renderer

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня проблема, я хочу исправить баг, когда мой 2д персонаж сталкивается с препятствием и умирает от него, то препятствие вылазиет на первый план из за другого препятствия, я хотел исправить это добовляя каждому препятствию Order in Layer из SpriteRenderer больше на 1 при их генерации, но у меня не получается изменить данный параметр через код, я искал алтернативу и ничего не нашол, может вы знаете решение?

Comment: SpriteRenderer renderer;
        renderer.sortingLayerID = yourValue

Comment: а можно вообще для них отдельный слой создать